# Trend VS. Blend

Tags: grammar, word-usage, sentence-meaning

Is it correct to use the world **"trends"** in the following sentence? or is it better to use **"blends"** instead of "trends"?

"In recent years, we face the emergence of new **trends** of location-based services in which users disclose not only their locations but also the semantic information of their locations."

An alternative would be to use **"types"** instead of **"trends"** but I would like to emphasis the fact that these new services are not very different from the original services, thus, they do not from a different type.

Comment: It's right to use the word which conveys the meaning you intend.  Those two words have distinctly different meanings.  (I suspect that you do not mean "blends", but I'm not sure.)  "Types" and "trends" have roughly the same meaning in your context, but "trends **of** ... services" is not idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

I'd reformulate it to indicate we're seeing a pattern of similar activity (trend). Blend is absolutely incorrect.

"In recent years, we've seen the emergence of a new trend of location-based services requiring users to disclose not just their locations, but also the semantic information associated with it."

I dont understand the last section (the semantic information of their location???) but ignoring that, the above sounds better

Comment: Thanks! I am just wondering if your proposed sentence remains still correct if I add some examples as below:
In recent years, we’ve seen the emergence of a new trend of location-based services (LBSs) (e.g., Foursquare, Facebook Places and Google Plus) requiring users to disclose not just their locations, but also the semantic information associated with their locations.

Comment: Yes, it's fine but I'd change it so you do not have two sets of parenthesis next to each other. So: "In recent years, we’ve seen the emergence of a new trend of location-based services (LBSs) such as Foursquare, Facebook Places and Google Plus  that require users to disclose not just their locations, but also the semantic information associated with their locations."